# Make android Spinner Serializable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

I tried to make Spinner object Serializable like that:

```
public class CustomSpinner implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 46548976L;

    private Spinner m_spinner = null;

    public CustomSpinner(Spinner spinner)
    {
        m_spinner = spinner;
    }

    public Spinner getSpinner()
    {
        return m_spinner;
    }
}
```

for sending it to the "another activity"(lets say AnotherActivity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
CustomSpinner customSpinner = new CustomSpinner(new Spinner(this));
intent.putExtra(SPINNER_OUTPUT, customSpinner);
startActivity(intent);
```

crash occurs.

**Is there a way to send Spinner(or another android widget) object via Intent?**

P.S: I know that I could just send ArrayList of Spinner values.

Comment: I don't think this would work, and I wouldn't do this anyway for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Is there a info why android widgets couldn't be sent via Intent?... Just interesting :) Thanks for reply!

Comment: Why would you want to?